# Using InfoMessage to display SQL Server messages in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm looking to take the message printed from a SQL Server stored procedure and display in a listbox in C#. Is using `InfoMessage` a good start?

I'm connecting to the database using SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and SqlDataReader.

Comment: How are you talking with the SQL DB? Without knowing how you connect to it, the answer will vary.

Comment: Using SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and SqlDataReader

Answer (score 0):

Here' a good example for your question.

```
public DataTable MyExample(string connectionString)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (DALHelper dal = new DALHelper(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            dal.OpenDB();
            ParameterInfo[] param = new ParameterInfo[0];
            ds = dal.ExecuteDataSet("StoredProcedure", CommandType.StoredProcedure, param);
        }
        //Here where message goes. if there's an error. So it's up to you.
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            throw er;
        }
        finally
        {
        //Here is, if successful..
        //Do the Code here....
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help! ^_^